# MTM Coded UI Test Manual Execution: "Recording Not Found"

Tags: unit-testing, testing, coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I have made a few coded UI tests to test the application I am working on. I followed the following post: [How to run coded UI Tests from MTM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553270.aspx) as a guidance and also the following post on how to create a fake build: [How to Create a Fake Build Definition and a Fake Build](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/02/23/creating-fake-builds-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx)

So after I set the infrastructure I attempted to run the tests from the Microsoft Test Manager (MTM). While MTM doesn't break or throw errors, the result it reports back to me is that it cannot find the Coded UI Test recordings.

Upon looking the contents of the first link (How to run coded UI tests from MTM) I noticed that there was a small piece of text saying `"You must create a build definition that just has a share location added that is where your assemblies for your tests are located."`

What exactly does that mean? How do I do this? My build definition drops the assemblies in `\\machine\share`, so that's where I copied the coded ui tests, but I still get the same result.

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

Well,I don't like to leave questions unanswered, so I thought to come back to this one.

The build definition's drop folder is the one that defines where the MTM is going to look for the coded ui test recordings/dlls.

In order for this to work, one simply has to build and compile their tests/coded ui tests and put the resulting assembly and resources in the folder defined in the build definition.

Cheers!